# htaccess not work with virtualdocumentroot

Tags: apache, .htaccess, virtualhost

I want change the root of one project without change the virtualhost but my htaccess is ignored

my virtualhost configuration

#### /etc/apache2/sites-available/localhost.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerAdmin email@example.com
   UseCanonicalName Off
   ServerAlias *.localhost
   VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/%-2
   <Directory /var/www/%-2>
      Options FollowSymLinks
      AllowOverride All
   </Directory>
   ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/localhost-error.log
   LogLevel warn
   CustomLog /var/log/apache2/localhost-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

and my htaccess

#### /var/www/test/.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /build
```

---

#### Solved

I found the solution

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerAdmin email@example.com
   UseCanonicalName Off
   ServerAlias *.localhost
   VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/%-2
   <Directory /var/www/*>
      Options FollowSymLinks
      AllowOverride All
   </Directory>
   ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/localhost-error.log
   LogLevel warn
   CustomLog /var/log/apache2/localhost-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

and htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase !^build/ /build%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

now test.localhost use /var/www/test/build as root :)

Answer (score 1):

```
   <Directory /var/www/%-2>
```

You can only use this type of variable in directives provided by mod_vhost_alias, not in any other directives.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /build
```

If this is the entirety, this doesn't actually do anything.  To see if the file is ignored, add some nonsense characters to it and make sure it returns an ISE 500 error.